# BibTeX not filling the BBL-file properly

Tags: bibtex

I am getting started with `BibTeX` using [this](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/bibtex/) tutorial.

My TeX-File:

```
% !TeX program = luatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% format font & encoding
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

% Babel & adjusted Titles
\usepackage[german]{babel}

% for figures
\usepackage{graphicx}  

% for adjusting the figure-position
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}


%some content stuff

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{foo} 
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

My `foo.bib`-file so far:

```
@misc{luaAbout,
     title={the programming language lua}, 
     url={https://www.lua.org/about.html}, 
     journal={The Programming Language Lua}
 }
```

This is what was in my `.bbl`-file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\end{thebibliography}
```

It looks like the `.bbl`-file would not be filled properly (this is not the first time I tried to work with BibTeX and had problems with the `.bbl`-file), what did I do wrong? I am using TeXstudio btw.

Edit:

I deleted the `.bbl`-file and compiled again. The new output was the following:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{luaAbout}
``the programming language lua.''

\end{thebibliography}
```

Now I am still missing the `url`-tag. Are there problems converting it for BibTeX?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by the bbl not being filled properly. The `journal` field is only meaningful for entries of type `@article`; for sure, the `journal` field is ignored for entries of type `@misc`, which is BibTeX's "catch all" entry type.

Comment: @Mico My problem was that my .bbl file was empty (as written above). Now I updated my question (there is content now, after I deleted the old .bbl-file). Sadly I am missing the `url` and `journal` tags. Since you just told me, that `journal` is ignored, i am just missing the `url`. Are there also problems with it?

Comment: if and how `url` can be handled depends on the bibliographystyle. ieeetr.bst is quite old and I found no mention of url in it. Consider if you want to use the more modern biblatex/biber. Beside knowing url it can also handle unicode/utf8 much better than bibtex.

Comment: The `ieeetr` bibliography style, as already mentioned by @UlrikeFischer, is very old. In fact, it dates back to the early 1990s, a time when URLs were unknown to anyone except a few intrepid folk at CERN -- any even they almost certainly didn't dream about providing URL strings in a bibliographic entry. But then, why are you using the ancient `ieeetr` bib style? Have you considered using a more modern bib style such as `IEEEtran`?

Comment: Incidentally, the first line of your sample code, `% !TeX program = luatex`, should almost certainly be `% !TeX program = lualatex`. For sure, the plain-LuaTeX  compiler will choke when it encounters the `\documentclass` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the positively-ancient `ieeetr` bibliography style. That particular bibliography style has been around since the very beginnings of BibTeX in the 1980s. `ieeetr` was last updated meaningfully in the early 1990s, a time when nobody thought about including URL strings in bibliographic entries -- assuming, of course, that they had even heard about this new-fangled thing called a URL.

The newer `IEEEtran` bibliography style is programmed not to ingnore `url` fields for most entry types.

The entry type `@misc` is BibTeX's catch-all entry type. One thing it does *not* process is fields of type `journal`. The only BibTeX entry type that does anything with the `journal` field is called `@article`; it is meant to be use for pieces that were published in scholarly journals.

Here's a revised version of your sample code, along with its output.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@misc{luaAbout, 
     title={About {Lua}},
     url  ={https://www.lua.org/about.html}, 
     year =2016,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% font handling
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

% Babel & adjusted titles
\usepackage[german]{babel}

% for figures
\usepackage{graphicx}  

% for adjusting the figure-position
\usepackage{float}

% for typesetting URLs
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}

% choose a bibliography style
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

% other packages
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

% finally, the 'document' environment and its contents
\begin{document}
\cite{luaAbout}
\bibliography{foo} 
\end{document}
```